# LISTAGG function with two columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have one table like this (report)

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  user_id |  Department | Position  | Record_id |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1       |  Science    | Professor |  1001     |
|  1       |  Maths      |           |  1002     |
|  1       |  History    | Teacher   |  1003     |
|  2       |  Science    | Professor |  1004     |
|  2       |  Chemistry  | Assistant |  1005     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to have the following result

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   | user_id  |  Department+Position                       |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   |  1       | Science,Professor;Maths, ; History,Teacher |
   |  2       | Science, Professor; Chemistry, Assistant   |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
```

That means I need to preserve the empty space as ' ' as you can see in the result table.
Now I know how to use LISTAGG function but only for one column. However, I can't exactly figure out how can I do for two columns at the sametime. Here is my query:

```
SELECT user_id, LISTAGG(department, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY record_id)
FROM report
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It just requires judicious use of concatenation within the aggregation:

```
select user_id
     , listagg(department || ',' || coalesce(position, ' '), '; ')
        within group ( order by record_id )
  from report
 group by user_id
```

i.e. aggregate the concatentation of `department` with a comma and `position` and replace `position` with a space if it is NULL.

Comment: lol like the updated comment 5 years later.  NVL is evil use: coalesce https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750233/458741  +1 for improving legacy answers.

Comment: missing group by clause

Comment: Thanks @gauti; I've fixed it. Somewhat surprised no one (including me) noticed in 6 years!

Comment: Great. Thanks for considering it @Ben !