# Why is Oracle's DECODE giving me a different value than NVL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, decode, to-char

This query:

```
select nvl(0.75,0) from dual
```

gives me `0.75` (numeric) but this query:

```
select decode(1,0,null,0.75) from dual
```

gives me `'.75'` (string).

Why?

I tried to fix this by changing the second query to:

```
select decode(1,0,null,to_char(0.75,'0.99')) from dual
```

but in my actual code the 0.75 will be a field (NUMBER) that may have a different number of decimal places and I'm not suppose to add/remove anything from that value.

Any ideas on how to fix the missing zero issue but still support all possible decimal lengths?

Comment: You should try to use Coalesce() instead of Nvl(), and Case instead of Decode(), for various reasons explained elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the 3<sup>rd</sup> parameter of your decode statement is NULL; as per [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions049.htm#sthref1068)<sup>1</sup> (my emphasis).

> Oracle automatically converts expr and each search value to the **data type of the first search value before comparing**.... If the first result has the data type CHAR or **if the first result is null, then Oracle converts the return value to the data type VARCHAR2**.

In your case the first result is NULL, which Oracle treats as a VARCHAR2. Your return value is being implicitly converted to a VARCHAR2. If you changed your `DECODE()` to the following you'd get a number:

```
select decode(1, 0, 0, 0.75)
```

and you could achieve your NULL by using the [`NULLIF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions116.htm#sthref1303) function:

```
select nullif(decode(1, 0, 0, 0.75), 0) ...
```

It's better to use a CASE statement, which enforces that all returned datatypes are the same:

```
select case 1 when 0 then null
              else 0.75
       end ...
```

<sub>1. which I've been caught out on as well.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
select decode(1,0,to_number(null),0.75) from dual
```

Comment: what? please describe more! what do you want to say?

Comment: in decode function if first result parameter is string then oracle implicitly converts other result parameter to string. In this case null is considered as string,so oracle converts 0.75 to string and gives .75 if u use to_number(null) then that null is converted to numeric and oracle gives result as 0.75

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `nvl()` is returning a numeric value. How to display that is up to the program you are using to run your queries. *TOAD* displays it like you said, 0.75.

In the second example, `decode()` is returning a `varchar2`. When Oracle converts a number to a string without any formatting, this is what you get, i.e. ".75".

From the Oracle docs on `decode()`:

> If the first result has the datatype CHAR or if the first result is
>   null, then Oracle converts the return value to the datatype VARCHAR2.

You could use a number format and `rtrim()` to achieve your purpose, e.g.:

```
select rtrim(to_char(.75, '9990.99999999999999'),'0') from dual;
```

Result:

```
0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_number(decode(1,0,null,0.75)) from dual
```